# Can't find a way to receive Mqtts Messages

Tags: vb.net, mqtt

I'm creating an app in vb.net and i need to receive and send mqtt message from and to a mosqitto mqtt broker, the connection and the sending works, but for the receiving message i can't find any code.

I'm using some translated code from the M2Mqtt library(the documentation is in c#).

I tried other libraries too, but i can't find a way to receive those message.

I'm using the same concept in a Xamarin Android app(c#) with the same library and it works correctly.

This is the code to connect to the iot, in this case a sonoff, and to shut it down:

```
    Dim client As MqttClient = New MqttClient("broker.chtulhu.org")

    Dim clientId As String = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
    client.Connect(clientId)
    client.Subscribe(New String() {"/home/sonoff"}, New Byte() {MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_AT_LEAST_ONCE})

    client.Publish("/home/sonoff/1/cmnd/", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("0"), MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_AT_LEAST_ONCE, False)
```

This is the code to receive the message and pass it to a simple sub to print it:

```
AddHandler client.MqttMsgPublishReceived, AddressOf client_MqttMsgPublishReceived(client.MqttMsgPublishReceived)
```

Comment: Will you post some code of what you've done so far, and what errors you have?

Comment: Added code to the post, sry for not doing that before

Comment: broker.chtulhu.org does not exist.

Comment: yeah, is a placeholder, but the mqtt broker runs in local net

Comment: can't you use a working public broker, until you've done debugging? Just to make sure it's not a broken broker service (unvoluntary pun).

Comment: nope, btw the server works, i'm currently using the same server in a c# android and in a c# ios app with the device i want to use connected and working 24\7

Comment: ok, what errors you've got? Can you describe better what is the point where you think it doesn't work

Comment: literally  just don't receive the messages but no error